# Fetch details about businesses on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, maps

I need to fetch details about businesses, services, etc., from Facebook in order to visualize them on a geographical map.

I have read the policy published by Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/policy) but I did not understand whether the restrictions apply to businesses etc., or only to the accounts of people (terms only mention "users").

Can anybody help me? In particular, do you think that, in order to fetch data about, e.g., a restaurant, I need its consent?

Indeed, is it legal show them on a geographical map?

Comment: Are you building a Facebook- app or an external app? Answers may vary based on your location as well as the location of the business. Also, it might make a difference if you are using this data for profit or not. Any particular reason you are not using something like Google Maps?

Comment: We are using this data for a research project - no-profit. Our application is an external app. We are not using Google Maps because they forbid the ingretation of their data into a map different from the own and our system generates dynamic maps based on an OpenStreetMap layer and a set of OpenData. Our location is Italy, while in principle businesses might be located anywhere. Thank you in advance for your help!